# random normal as Integer in array

Tags: perl

I am trying to make my array contain integers but because I use `random_normal` its giving me back a list of floats. How can I get a list of integers?

It would also be great if I could count the number of duplicates in my array too.

```
use strict;

use Math::Random qw(:all);

my @rand_arr = random_normal(1000,50,5);
print "@rand_arr \n";
```

Comment: Apparently, that function produces floats, deal with it. But how do you want to round each number: Up, down, away from 0, towards zero, normal? (Style note: Please separate words in a function name by underscores, and choose shorter, more semantically descriptive names)

Comment: its cant be.. there is for sure a way to make it give back integer...

Comment: @user2976056 The [`Math::Random` docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random) mention no way how that would ever return integers (which are useless whenever you are working with probabilities). But rounding them really isn't difficult – once you decide *how* you want to round.

Comment: @amon's comments are precise, correct and helpful. You shouldn't be complaining to him about a feature that your language doesn't have (and you erroneously think it should have).

Comment: thanks for the Answer.. ok, so if i understand you right , icant make the random output as Integer? what do u  find better to round up or down ? iam an beginner so what u think ?

Comment: iam gonna keep that in mind thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take integer portion of numbers,

```
use Math::Random qw(:all);

my @rand_arr = map int, random_normal(1000,50,5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, usually, if people have a floating point value (ie: 5.5 ), and they want an integer, they tend to round it, "somehow". Though "somehow" depends on what you want, as @amon says.

- floor : 5 → 5, 5.1 → 5, 5.5 → 5, 5.9 → 5 , 6 → 6
- ceil  : 5 → 5, 5.1 → 6, 5.5 → 6, 5.9 → 6 , 6 → 6
- round : 5 → 5, 5.1 → 5, 5.5 → 6, 5.9 → 6 , 6 → 6

Though as to which method to use, and how to use it, `perldoc -q round` answers this clearly:

> **Does Perl have a round() function? What about ceil() and floor()?
>   Trig functions?**
>
> Remember that "int()" merely truncates toward 0. For rounding to a certain
>   number of digits, "sprintf()" or "printf()" is usually the easiest route.
>
> ```
>     printf("%.3f", 3.1415926535);   # prints 3.142
> ```
>
> The POSIX module (part of the standard Perl distribution) implements
>   "ceil()", "floor()", and a number of other mathematical and trigonometric
>   functions.
>
> ```
>     use POSIX;
>     my $ceil   = ceil(3.5);   # 4
>     my $floor  = floor(3.5);  # 3
> ```
>
> In 5.000 to 5.003 perls, trigonometry was done in the Math::Complex
>   module. With 5.004, the Math::Trig module (part of the standard Perl
>   distribution) implements the trigonometric functions. Internally it uses
>   the Math::Complex module and some functions can break out from the real
>   axis into the complex plane, for example the inverse sine of 2.
>
> Rounding in financial applications can have serious implications, and the
>   rounding method used should be specified precisely. In these cases, it
>   probably pays not to trust whichever system of rounding is being used by
>   Perl, but instead to implement the rounding function you need yourself.
>
> To see why, notice how you'll still have an issue on half-way-point
>   alternation:
>
> ```
>     for (my $i = 0; $i < 1.01; $i += 0.05) { printf "%.1f ",$i}
>
>     0.0 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7
>     0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 1.0 1.0
> ```
>
> Don't blame Perl. It's the same as in C. IEEE says we have to do this.
>   Perl numbers whose absolute values are integers under 2**31 (on 32-bit
>   machines) will work pretty much like mathematical integers. Other numbers
>   are not guaranteed.

Using one of the above functions in conjunction with random_normal is pretty easy

```
my @values = map { some_function($_) } random_normal(1000,50,5);
```

Just be aware, that depending on what you're doing with those numbers, the rounding method used might be incredibly important.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Math::Random qw(random_normal);

my $buckets = {};

sub round { 
  return 0 + sprintf "%.0f", $_[0];
}

for my $int ( map { round($_) } random_normal(1000,50,5) ) {
  $buckets->{$int} //= 0;
  $buckets->{$int} ++;
}
for my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$buckets ) {
  printf "%s %s\n", $key, $buckets->{$key};
}
```

After a couple of runs of this program, you might realize that your choice to round was a bad idea, because rounding causes integer buckets to overfill, breaking normal distribution slightly:

```
34 2
36 1    # Trough
37 3
38 5
39 11   # Spike
40 9
41 25
42 21
43 24
44 43
45 51   
46 48   # Trough
47 69
48 62
49 79
50 77
51 71
52 82
53 71
54 66
55 47
56 38
57 33
58 15   # Trough
59 21
60 8
61 9    # Spike
63 4
64 3
65 1
66 1
```